# Why does the function return false?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to shorten out the following code:

```
var a = 0, b = 0;

function() {
    return a === 0 && b === 0; // returns 'true'
}
```

So, I thought something like the following would do:

```
var a = 0, b = 0;

function() {
    return a === b === 0; // returns 'false'
}
```

Initially, I thought that such syntax would throw an error, but apparently it returns **`false`**. Why does **`a === b === 0`** return **`false`**?

Comment: [Simple Google search: site:stackoverflow.com javascript a === b === c](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+a+%3D%3D%3D+b+%3D%3D%3D+c)

Comment: Sorry @squint, I didn't notice. I was kind of amazed it didn't throw an error that I just wanted to share it with someone :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `a === b === 0` is interpreted as if it were written `(a === b) === 0`. The result is `false` because `(a === b)` gives `true`, and `true` is not `===` to `0`.

One can imagine a programming language that would understand a chain of expressions connected by `==` or `===` or whatever, meaning that all values should be compared in one big "group equality" comparison. JavaScript is not such a language, however.

Comment: Aha, I knew I was missing something. Thanks @Pointy

Comment: Whoa, 9 upvotes in 3 minutes, with the blatant duplicate mentioned in the "related questions" sidebar…

Comment: @Bergi I guess people are bored? Or maybe I'm magic.

Comment: @Bergi I did look for a duplicate but I don't understand SO search so I'm bad at it.

Comment: @Pointy: I guess you're magic :-) But yes, search is weird, especially that "search", "duplicate search" and "related" seems to use different algorithms that bring up results of very different relevance. And then, as squint mentions, there's Google, which finds some altogether different things.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to how operators are evaluated. In JavaScript, equality operators are evaluated left-to-right (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

This means that this:

```
a === b === 0
```

Becomes this after one step:

```
true === 0
```

Since the number zero is not equal to the boolean true, your expression returns false.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Robert

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Kobi thanks, fixed it